# Display data horzontally and vertically in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005

I have a problem to display a data from the database. I have 6 columns(EmpName, EmpID, AdminCode, Practice, Hours, FTE) in my table and I want to display that data as below

```
blankArea       blankArea   blankarea        P1(PracticeName)    P2              P3
EmpName         EmpID      AdminCode     Hours   FTE        Hours   FTE     Hours    FTE

A                1          Insurance    0.14    0.03        0.00  0.00     0.00    0.00
A                1          AllDocs      0.19    0.04        0.00  0.00     0.00    0.00
B                2          Insurance    0.52    0.11        1.18  0.25     0.00    0.00
B                2          Payments     1.18    0.35        0.00  0.00     0.00    0.00
C                3          Payments     1.31    0.00        0.00  0.00     0.00    0.00
```

It means all details are in my table practice name is also in table and I use sql server 2005. How can I display my data as above format. Practice name is display horizontally and two columns are generated automatically and fill those columns with Hours and FTE column data which is exist in database.
Is repeater or datalist suitable for this. If yes then how. Have you any code regarding this. Please help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a [GridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.aspx) and it's [RowCreated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcreated.aspx) Event to generate the extra row in the header:

ASPX:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnRowCreated="GridView1_RowCreated" ></asp:GridView>
```

Codebehind(VB.Net):

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        'fake data
        Dim tbl As New DataTable
        tbl.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("EmpName", GetType(String)))
        tbl.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("EmpID", GetType(String)))
        tbl.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("AdminCode", GetType(String)))
        tbl.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("P1Hours", GetType(String)))
        tbl.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("P1FTE", GetType(String)))
        tbl.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("P2Hours", GetType(String)))
        tbl.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("P2FTE", GetType(String)))
        tbl.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("P3Hours", GetType(String)))
        tbl.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("P3FTE", GetType(String)))
        For i As Int32 = 1 To 100
            Dim newRow = tbl.NewRow
            newRow("EmpName") = "EmpName" & i
            newRow("EmpID") = "EmpID" & i
            newRow("AdminCode") = "AdminCode" & i
            newRow("P1Hours") = "P1Hours" & i
            newRow("P1FTE") = "P1FTE" & i
            newRow("P2Hours") = "P2Hours" & i
            newRow("P2FTE") = "P2FTE" & i
            newRow("P3Hours") = "P3Hours" & i
            newRow("P3FTE") = "P3FTE" & i
            tbl.Rows.Add(newRow)
        Next
        Me.GridView1.DataSource = tbl
        Me.GridView1.DataBind()
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub GridView1_RowCreated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs)
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.Header Then
        'Build own custom header.
        Dim grid As GridView = DirectCast(sender, GridView)
        Dim newHeaderRow As New GridViewRow(0, 0, DataControlRowType.Header, DataControlRowState.Insert)
        Dim oTableCell As New TableCell()

        'Add empty cell
        newHeaderRow.Cells.Add(oTableCell)

        'Add empty cell
        oTableCell = New TableCell()
        newHeaderRow.Cells.Add(oTableCell)

        'Add empty cell
        oTableCell = New TableCell()
        newHeaderRow.Cells.Add(oTableCell)

        'Add P1(PracticeName)-Cell
        oTableCell = New TableCell()
        oTableCell.Text = "P1(PracticeName)"
        oTableCell.ColumnSpan = 2
        oTableCell.Font.Bold = True
        oTableCell.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center
        newHeaderRow.Cells.Add(oTableCell)

        'Add P2-Cell
        oTableCell = New TableCell()
        oTableCell.Text = "P2"
        oTableCell.ColumnSpan = 2
        oTableCell.Font.Bold = True
        oTableCell.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center
        newHeaderRow.Cells.Add(oTableCell)

        'Add P3-Cell
        oTableCell = New TableCell()
        oTableCell.Text = "P3"
        oTableCell.ColumnSpan = 2
        oTableCell.Font.Bold = True
        oTableCell.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center
        newHeaderRow.Cells.Add(oTableCell)
        grid.Controls(0).Controls.AddAt(0, newHeaderRow)
    End If
End Sub
```

If you need C#, you can convert it [here](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/).

This is the result:

[image: image of the resulting GridView]

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that pops up in my mind is to make:

- One global Gridview with: EmpName, EmpID, AdminCode, Practices
- One repeater displayed in the Practices itemtemplate of the global gridview.
- Another gridview with the details of one practices, this gridview will be in the repeater and therefor repeated for each and every practice.

This is what I should do, maybe there is an easier way not sure.
Hope this will put you on track.